# Why can't I append a PDF to another PDF with this code using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf, itext, append

I'm trying to combine the contents of two PDF files into one new PDF file using iTextSharp. I've used PDFStamper before to accomplish this in similar situations, but it isn't working this time for some reason. Appending doesn't work at all; the file is created, but the size stays at 0 bytes by the end of this block of code. Any assistance anybody can provide will be greatly appreciated.

```
File.Create(session.getLocalDir() + newPdfFile);

// pasting content from original file to new file
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(originalFile);
string pageSelection = "1-" + reader.NumberOfPages;
reader.SelectPages(pageSelection);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newPdfFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();

// pasting content from temp file to new file
reader = new PdfReader(temp);
pageSelection = "1-" + reader.NumberOfPages;
reader.SelectPages(pageSelection);
stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newPdfFile, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write));
stamper.Close();
reader.Close();
```

Comment: What did you observe when you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: Well that's just it, it doesn't throw an exception or otherwise indicate anything wrong occurred. But the appending doesn't occur for neither the original nor the temp file.

Comment: It isn't clear why the result file is 0 bytes long, but appending as you try won't work anyhow. You cannot simply concatenate two pdfs and hope that the result would be the merger of them.

Comment: I'm not asking about exceptions. I'm asking about whether each line of code meets your expectations as you execute it. If your expectations are simply that the program doesn't crash or throw an exception, your code works! I doubt they're so limited as that, though. The expectations of each line should be specific to that line.

Comment: No, it isn't working according to my expectations. Like I mentioned in my original post, I have successfully appended to a PDF using this method before. The only difference was that I was not using a PDF I explicitly created, like I do in the above code. Perhaps that's the issue. But is there a better way I might merge two PDFs into one new one?

Comment: *"I have successfully appended to a PDF using this method before"* - I doubt that because the PDF format does not allow for merging PDF files by concatenating them. Probably there are viewers that *repair* the hodgepodge generated by that approach and display it as intended (PDF viewers are notorious for repairing PDFs under the hood) but that does not make the PDF valid, nor can you count on other PDF processors doing the same.

Comment: Regardless, it was functional. Which is all that I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution here would be to use a MemoryStream to save the temporary pdf file while you are adding to it. After some research I've found that as mkl suggests the PdfStamper class is unsuited for this operation. In iTextSharp you can append 2 PDF's using another way:

```
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfCopyFields copy = new PdfCopyFields(stream);


        var ms1 = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file1Path));
        ms1.Position = 0;
        copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ms1));
        ms1.Dispose();

        var ms2 = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(file2Path));
        ms2.Position = 0;
        copy.AddDocument(new PdfReader(ms2));
        ms2.Dispose();
        copy.Close();
```

The resulting 'stream' variable contains the combined PDF's and can be written to a file using the PdfStamper.

If switching to iText 7 for .net is an option, the PdfStamper can be omitted and PdfDocument.copyPagesTo() method can be used instead.

a simple example (With iText 7 for .net):

```
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfDocument outputDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(stream));
    PdfDocument pdfSource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("c:\\firstInput.pdf"));

    pdfSource.CopyPagesTo(1, pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages(), outputDocument);
    pdfSource = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("c:\\secondInput.pdf"));
    pdfSource.CopyPagesTo(1, pdfSource.GetNumberOfPages(), outputDocument);
    pdfSource.Close();
    outputDocument.Close();

    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
    outputDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(outputStream), new PdfWriter("c:\\result.pdf"));
```

Edited a second time with a solution to the specific use case.